# SuiteCRM turn ON autocomplete on email recipient field

Tags: autocomplete, sugarcrm, suitecrm

I'm trying to remove the `autocomplete="off"` attribute from the input field for the email recipient field

The code of the input field is as follows:

```
<input 
    class="ac_input yui-ac-input" 
    size="96" 
    id="addressTO1" 
    title="An" 
    name="addressTO1"
    onkeyup="SE.composeLayout.showAddressDetails(this);"
    autocomplete="off" type="text">
```

Is there a setting that can be accessed via the GUI that changes the behaviour of the email "to" field or what would be the best way to turn on the autocomplete functionality.

Just removing it does not work, as there is some javascript functionality there, that keeps bringing it back.

I'm using suiterCRM version 7.6.5
Sugar Version 6.5.23.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no GUI for changing that, the `autocomplete=off` is hardcoded.

The TO field (`addressTO1` dynamically generated name) is not a regular text input field, it will support multiple emails separated by comma, so a `autocomplete="email"`  will not work.

The only solution I could come up with is for you to create a javascript function and attach to the keyup event of the field and show your logic.

Also you will need to save previously filled input with the answers and provide a mechanism to delete that.  Not an easy solution I am afraid.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, maybe I did not form my question well...
I'm trying to turn the autocomplete on (therefore remove the autocomplete=off option. because the emails that were previously used, are not showing up in the autocomplete.

Comment: thank you for the update. I'm now understanding that just changing the autocomplete attribute won't do much for me (given that there can be more email addresses separated with comma). There has to be some way of having the "autocomplete" where you start typing the email address of someone that you contacted (emailed with) previously and get the option to select from the list of options? Is there a module that does that or something similar. I can't imagine such common feature not being supported right out of the box almost.

Comment: Not that I am aware of, the email client was really crap, only recently its receiving some serious work, so I suggest to drop in your recommendation on github and find stars :)